# Custom search for a custom post type in WordPress

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, search, tax-query

I have created a custom search for a custom post type in WordPress that searches car vehicles.
I can search by manufacturer and model but I want the search to be flexible and show results based on any manufacturer or model. Currently, the search will show results if only the manufacturer and model are exact from drop down options. For example, if I choose BMW from the list of manufacturers, then choose E Class from the model, I want the search to display all BMWs and all Mercedes E Classes. Currently it will display no results (which is correct in real world environemnt), but I want to be more flexible and show any BMW vehicles and any E class vehicles

Here is my code...

```
if (!empty($_POST['searchfeatures'])) {
    $feature_slugs = $_POST['searchfeatures']; 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'listing',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'features',
                'terms'    => $feature_slugs,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => 'AND',
            ),
        ),
    );
    //print_r($args);
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        //$post = $the_query->post;

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $arr_features[] = $post->ID;
        }
    } else {
        $features_status = "No Results";
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} 
}
```

My search only shows results based on if the terms are exact whereas I need the results to show based on any terms selected. I have tried adding the "relation" parameter and using 'OR' as its value but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just a sidenote: it's necessary to validate and/or sanitize the incoming user input before passing it on in your script. You could use ie. `filter_input()` for this.

Comment: @Michael You don't need to sanitise it if you're just using it in a query. `WP_Query` does that for you. As for validation, in this particular case if someone  happens to post an invalid value they just won't get any results, so it doesn't seem necessary to me.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Sorry, I don't agree at all. Sanitizing user input is not use case specific, it's a must that one should *always* consider. In this example, a user might add additional `'` to his input, creating different query args than expected. While this might not be harmful, it surely is not what the script owner wants.

Comment: What format does `$feature_slugs` have? Array, comma seperated?

Comment: You're confusing sanitisation and validation. Your example is validation. Regardless, if the form is using a `<select>`, radio buttons or checkboxes for these variables then the only way they'd be incorrect is if the user was editing the page source or sending a request externally from the form. In both cases showing no results is a perfectly acceptable way to handle that. Besides, `filter_input()` wouldn't handle your example anyway.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your last sentence. As the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php) states, `filter_input` can be used for both sanitization and validation. Removing additional quotes from a string is surely not validation, from all I know. I'm not checking the input value for a data type or a specific format. After all, it is about *checking* user input before *processing* it.

Comment: Why would you be removing a quote for sanitisation? As I said, WP_Query already does this for you.

Comment: This got me thinking a bit, so I made a post here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/379038/should-we-delegate-user-input-sanitization-validation

Answer (score 0):

Change `operator` to `IN`:

```
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'features',
    'terms'    => $feature_slugs,
    'field' => 'slug',
    'operator' => 'IN',
),
```

That will query posts that have *any* of the terms in `$feature_slugs`, rather than *all* of the terms, which is what `AND` does.

Also, I can see you're using the `POST` method for this search. That type of request is inappropriate here. When you are requesting data you should be using a `GET` request and accessing the data with `$_GET[]`.

`POST` should only be used when sending data to the server to be processed, usually when it will create or update a resource.